# NullPointerException on assigning value to 2D Object List

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, tablemodel

I am trying to assign Strings to a 2D Object List, however I encounter a NullPointerException every time. The 2D Object List is the data source for a Custom Table Model class that feeds it to a JTable.
The Source is a 2D String List that consists ONLY of pairs of data, however both parts are Strings that need to be printed so a Map is not suitable.
I iterate through the source list and set the value of the table data list.

```
public class CustomTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<List<Object>> tableData = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setValues(List<List<String>> values) {

        //Sanity Check
        if (values == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values cannot be null");
        } else {

            System.out.println("Got values in table model");

            //Iterate through and set table data
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (List<String> l : values) {
                for (String s : l) {
                    setValueAt(s, i, j);
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
                //Reset to 0 as only 2 colums needed
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Further down is the setValueAt method

```
   @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        System.out.println("Setting" + value + " at " + rowIndex + "," + columnIndex);
        //This gives a NullPointerException
        tableData.get(rowIndex).set(columnIndex, value);
        //
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
```

The debugger shows that all the values in

```
tableData.get(rowIndex).set(columnIndex, value);
```

are there and non-null.

I'm sure that a String is an Object, but what is null here?

**EDIT:**

I have declared and initialised as an ArrayList instead:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> tableData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

And updated setValueAt to:

```
                @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        System.out.println("Setting" + value + " at " + rowIndex + "," + columnIndex);
        //This causes IndexOutOfBoundsException
        if(tableData.get(rowIndex) == null){
            tableData.add(rowIndex, new ArrayList<>());
        }else{
            tableData.get(rowIndex).add(columnIndex, value);
            //Called after both columns in a row are populated
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
        
    }
```

However it gives an IndexOutOfBoundsException when calling get() on tableData in the if condition. If it was null, it should execute the first block of the if statement?

Comment: And we count the seconds until @BobMalooga closes this question as duplicate, because "Well, as you should know, every NPE fires from the same origin". (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022248/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-pass-data-to-a-fragment?noredirect=1#comment61598934_37022248)

Comment: Break it down, make it easier to read, do this instead:
`List<Object> firstValue = tableData.get(rowIndex);
firstValue.set(columnIndex, value);`

That will at least point where the NPE is coming from

Comment: Where do you actually add lists to `tableData`? I see you're trying to *get* lists in your code, but you must *add* them if they don't exist. Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're initializing the `tableData` instance:

```
private List<List<Object>> tableData;
```

Without a proper constructor call this will be `null` and lead to the exception you're seeing.

---

In addition (and I'm not quite sure here, because my Java is not very fluent anymore): **If** `tableData` is not `null` it might be that the `get(index)` method - instead of throwing an index out of bounds error - just returns `null` if there is no element at the given index, so it might well be that you need to change this line

```
tableData.get(rowIndex).set(columnIndex, value);
```

to something like this:

```
List<string> elements = tableData.get(rowIndex);
if (elements == null)
{
    // Create elements list and add it to tableData
    ...
}
elements.set(columnIndex, value);
```

Comment: I have implemented this in the edit, however I needed to change tableData to an ArrayList because a List can't be instantiated in `tableData.add(rowIndex, new List<>());`

Comment: It solved it and created a new one, as per the edit. It now shows IndexOutOfBounds

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `rowIndex`, `columnIndex`, and `value` are all clearly set, then either `tableData` is null or the inner `List` obtained from the `get` is null.

You can determine which one by separating your statement into lines:

```
List<Object> row = tableData.get(rowIndex); //NPE means tableData is null
row.set(columnIndex, value); //NPE means inner List is null
```